# custom screen in Origami Studio

Tags: json, origami

I tried to create a galaxy custom screen (360x640) in Origami Studio, but it didn't work. i get this massage: The document “galaxyx.origamidevice” could not be opened.

I followed those instructions: http://origami.design/documentation/workflow/CustomDevices.html

here is the content of my json file:

```
{
  "key" : “galaxy x”,
  "displayName" : "galaxy x,
  "platform" : “Android”,
  "screenScale" : 2,
  "screenSize" : [
    720,
    1280
  ],
  "handsImageScale" : 0.5649999999999999,
  "handsImageOffset" : [
    2,
    45
  ],
  "handsImages" : [
    "iPhoneHands.png",
    "iPhoneHands2.png",
    "iPhoneHands3.png"
  ],
  "deviceInsets" : [
    130,
    28,
    130,
    28
  ],
  "deviceImages" : {
    "White" : "iPhone4-White.png",
    "Black" : "iPhone4-Black.png"
  },
  "shadowOffset" : [
    20,
    -5
  ],
}
```

Dose anyone have succeeded, and can show an example of a good json file?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's been 3 months, but it seems like you forgot a closing quotation mark at the end of `"displayName" : "galaxy x`